# Return lines in columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need write a query in SQL Server to do the following:

```
   TABLE cps_ctrl_proc_setor (

      cps_cd_indicador INTEGER  NOT NULL  ,
      cps_dt_ref DATETIME  NOT NULL  ,
      cps_vl_lancamento DECIMAL    )

    CREATE TABLE ind_indicador (
      ind_cd_indicador INTEGER  NOT NULL   IDENTITY,

      ind_nm_indicador VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL  ,

    )
```

In `IND_INDICADOR` for each `IND_INDICADOR` but in the CPS Table I got at last 12 registers for each `IND_INDICADOR` that represent 12 months.

I got only 1 register for each month and I need bring this registers like above:

```
nm_indicador, january/2013, fev/2013, mar/2013, etc.
```

Regardless of whether or not records in these months.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

First construct the full range of periods, then join/apply this period range on your results. Here is a sample to get a full range of of months for a given period.

```
DECLARE @from DATE= '20120101';
DECLARE @to DATE= '20121231';

WITH    Dates
          AS ( SELECT   @from AS [date]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(M, 1, [date])
               FROM     Dates
               WHERE    DATEADD(M, 1, [date]) <= @to )
    SELECT  [date]
           ,CAST(MONTH([date]) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR([date]) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [MonthOfYear]
    FROM    Dates;
```

Comment: Sayd i cant give a standard value to a local variable